# How to give "multiple" attribute to input file tag in jquery

Tags: jquery, django

Since I brought my HTML tags through Django form, I can't access the tags directly, so I wanna add some attributes through jQuery.

Here's input tag

```
<input id="id_photo" name="photo" type="file">
```

I wanna add `multiple` attribute to the input tag. So I did,

```
$('#id_photo').attr('multiple');
```

But it doesn't work, what should I do?

Comment: Using jQuery is not the right thing to do. Why can't you "access the tags directly"? You should be able to set the attribute for the widget in the Django form field definition.

Comment: @Daniel But the Django form field doesn't support `multiple` attribute. Isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the documentation, you need to pass a value for attr to set it, otherwise you are just getting it. I also recommend using `prop`

```js
$('#id_photo').attr('multiple', true);
// or this
$('#id_photo').prop('multiple', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="id_photo" name="photo" type="file">
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `setAttr`

For example

```
$('#id_photo').setAttr('multiple', true);
```

But if you create this input via django forms you can define attributes in your forms.py file like this

```
photo = forms.FileField(widget=widgets.FileInput(attrs={
    'multiple': True,
}))
```

Comment: Where did you get this method from `setAttr`? this is not a valid jQuery method.